# Comparing coefficients to understand the change in impact of a variable

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, operations-research

Our success measure (satisfaction) have dropped in July compared to June. I want to understand the factors that affected the drop. Since I could not create a flag that identify records that contributed to the drop vs. the one that did not, I came up with another way. I developed a regression model for June and another separate model for July, and used the change in each variable coefficient to explain the drop in outcome.
I have good sample size in each month (more than 20k), and I used the same variables in both months models.

1- Is that a good approach? 
2- All variables were significant in both months except one, it was significant in one month but not significant in the other month, how can I interpret that? Can I say the variable improved and it is now significant in impacting our success measure?
Thanks.